# Responsive Web Design (RWD) apply javascript by media query

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to use jquery to hide/show mobile navigation bar with a timeout based on vertical scroll.

I can't apply the function to the whole doc because I don't want this effect for the desktop view/media query (only the mobile and tablet).

Is it possible to direct jquery functions at a specific media query? Possibly if statement the window width?

Comment: Taak a look at the [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) I think this is exactly what they do.

Comment: show us what you want to apply.

Comment: @Jordy Thanks, but I'm not seeing much that looks promising on bootstrap, although scrollspy got my hopes up :(

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you need, you can do something like this: you have your CSS file with media-queries. This file automatically formats your html. But you want something more. So, you can write a jquery function based on window width.

```
$(function(){
 $(window).resize(function(){
     if($(this).width() >= "desired_width"){
                 //your function
         });
     }
  })
});
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then maybe incorporate something like this http://james.padolsey.com/demos/scrollevents/ to fade in/out a simple ul nav with fixed position at the bottom of the page. Sorry, on my mobile right now almost no code functionality on my mobile